# java gwt draw horizontal line

Tags: java, html, gwt

How can I draw a horizontal line in java gwt, something similar to the '< hr >' tag in HTML? I tried it by using

```
 com.google.gwt.user.client.Element bottomLine = DOM.createDiv();
```

but that somehow doesn't work in IE...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the HTML widget to add whatever html you want inside your page

```
HTML html = new HTML("<hr  style=\"width:100%;\" />")
rootPanel.add(html); // or add it inside another widget
```

Or you can use css on Panel and define the border-bottom property (if you have a panel that spans the entire page).

Comment: Good reference for styling <hr> within the HTML widget: http://css-tricks.com/simple-styles-for-horizontal-rules/
Keep in mind you'll have to give that style specificity to apply to the <hr> within the <div> that the HTML Widget wraps around it.

Answer (score 5):

`Document.get()`.[`createHRElement()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Document.html#createHRElement%28%29)?

Comment: I tried that, but could not figure out how to get around this error:
"Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy"

Not saying createHRElement won't work, but rather I just couldn't figure it all out, and ended up just using an HTML Widget like Athanasios Answered here.